# Is there a way to avoid package dependency warnings in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, package, package-managers

When I initialize a new React Native project, I get several warnings like

`warning react-native > create-react-class > fbjs > core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.8 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.`

and

`warning "react-native > metro-react-native-babel-transformer@0.54.1" has unmet peer dependency "@babel/core@*".`

When I look for solutions to these warnings, people recommend installing the necessary packages in the given project. Should I be trying to install things globally in order to avoid these warnings though? Or are these warnings just the fault of the packages that React Native uses, and there's no way/need for me to avoid them?

Answer (score 0):

is for you node version, but no problem you can fix with the command `npm audit fix` o install each that you see in the console

Comment: 'npm audit fix' This command can rather show the user a bad error. This is not the recommended method.

Answer (score 0):

React native is very huge and has many core dependencies.

Day by day they are trying to reduce the core dependencies by bifurcating the libraries into external sources.

ex : `AsyncStorage, netInfo` these were earlier into the core but now react native shipped them externally and if you want to use them you have to install it from external sources and then use them to get rid of yellow libraries error.

However if you always get stick to latest versions you might get rid of these errors.